# Synchronize 2 graphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

i'm new to dygraphs and I have a question concerning syncing 2 graphs. I'm using the synchronize.js

I have an HTML page with 3 tabs. A selection screen, tabGraphAggregated, tabGraphDetailed.

When the tabGraphAggregated loads (so when you click it), there is a .csv created and dygraph1 is created.

When the tabGraphDetailed is loaded (when you click it), there is a second .csv created and a new dygraph 2 is created.

What I want: I want the dygraph2 to be synced immediately after loading. Now i have to go back to tab2 to select my daterange. Any possibilities?

Comment: Show us your code, we won't be able to do much without it :)

Comment: I'm using this within a SAS stored process, the code is pretty heavy using different .sas codes and .js files.